# Docker on OSX with Certificate Authentication Proxy

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm using OSX 10.9 to run docker and am having issues using it. I was able to get around the initial Boot2Docker image pull by downloading it manually, but building my image fails due to the following:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 88.72 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM ubuntu
Pulling repository ubuntu
INFO[0003] Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have tried numerous things including setting the HTTP/S_PROXY values in the profile, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you re-install boot2docker again from [here](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/#install-boot2docker)?
Your error `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` is clearly due to certificate issue.

Comment: Agreed, thus the importance of the title, which I'm sure is the culprit. I downloaded and installed via the link you sent, and I'm receiving the following when running `boot2docker init`: `error in run: Failed to get latest release: Get https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Comment: could you possibly test using an iso from https://github.com/tianon/boot2docker/releases ? If this doesn't help, follow through this boot2docker [issue](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/819).